# Return outside function error eventhough it has been indented properly

Tags: django

Hi I know this error is kind of silly but I am new to django. I also have indented the return function properly but it keeps on saying return outside function. I hope someone can help.

Trace back:

```
 File "C:\simpleblog\ablog\myblog\models.py", line 26
    return render(request, 'profile_page.html', {'pro':pro})
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

models.py:

```
class UserProfileView(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/profile/')
    website_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    facebook_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    pinterest_utl = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    instagram_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    twitter_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    return render(request, 'profile_page.html', {'pro':pro})
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Comment: You seem to mix models with views...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return render(request, 'profile_page.html', {'pro': pro})` does not make much sense. A model is request unaware, and furthermore should *not* render any pages, that is what the views are for.

You can return the URL where you can find the page for the `UserProfile` by implementing the [**`.get_absolute_url()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url):

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # …
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('name-of-some-view', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

In a view you can then decide how to render a page, but you are mixing models and views, and this is not how Django's architecture works: in the `model.py` you define models that focus on how to *store* data in the database.

In the `views.py`, you make handlers that, for a HTTP request, will construct a HTTP response, and these can make use of the models to obtain and render data.

A view is thus a *function* that has a request (and URL parameters) as input, and turns this into a HTTP output. One can also implement *class-based views*, but the [**`.as_view(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) turns this into a function that handles HTTP requests and returns HTTP responses.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly I have to put whatever in my models into my views ad use the def function you gave instead of my return render.

Comment: @Kaushik: no, the view should import the model and likely make a query (or multiple queries) to load models from the database, and eventually construct a HTTP response, often by rendering a template.

Comment: I would suggest to reread the Django tutorial, since this explains effectively how views and models work in order to create a HTTP response.